# How to install timmywill panzoom with a script tag

Tags: javascript, wordpress, panzoom

I am trying to add panzoom to my page via a vanilla script tag. In the documentation it says:

> With a script tag:

```
<script src="/js/panzoom.js"></script>
```

I can not find a folder called js nor a file called panzoom.js in the package, only src/panzoom.**ts**. Trying to include this file causes an error:

> Refused to execute script from '…/panzoom.ts?ver=5.4.1' because its MIME type ('video/mp2t') is not executable.

How can I get this library to run? Is there no single js file I can add to my page?

Comment: I have to agree, some of the vaguest documentation ever. No guidance on how to build the above file, and not included in the repro either. Did you find a solution?

Comment: https://github.com/timmywil/panzoom/issues/537 some info here on this